# Azure App Service - How to set folder permission? (Window OS)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am a newbie of Azure Cloud (App Service) (coz my clients are using it).The simple question is, how to set folder permission to writable? (as in 777 in Linux).

I need to set 3 folders to be writable:

```
\wwwroot\public\data
\wwwroot\public\uploads
\wwwroot\ssr-data
```

I don't have any idea how to do that even I did lots of searching. Some of the tutorials are old. I am using Mac OS. Does Azure Cloud still support the Remote Desktop? I prefer using this if any.

Thanks for your great helps.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you explained why you need those folders to be writable. I strongly suspect there is a better solution you can use, instead of changing folder permissions, but we need more details from you please.

Comment: you should look at storing binary data in azure blob storage or file storage. if the app service recycles the data you put in the app service storage will be lost.

Comment: did you figure how to change permission on azure folders?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should be writable automatically after deploying. Azure App Service is a PaaS , so it's not supported to connect to a Remote Desktop.

1. If you really need to set the file permission, you could use the command line directly on KuDu site.

> Use CMD if you are using windows environment：`Icacls ${dirName} /grant ${userName}:F`
>
> Use SSH if you are using Linux environment： `chmod 777 ${dirName}`

2. You could write the file content directly on KuDu site, unless you deploy from ZIP, which would lock the file to Read-Only mode.
3. You could also choose Rest API to write file content.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Doris's suggestions - App Service is a PAAS solution- and it doesn't provide remote desktop access to the VM instances. The deployment mechanism is the action used to put your built application into the */home/site/wwwroot* directory of your web app.

App Service supports deployment mechanisms (Kudu endpoints) and FTP and WebDeploy.

As mentioned, the app directories are available for read and write access at runtime by the app's application code.

The home directory contains an app's content, and application code can write to it. If an app runs on multiple instances, the home directory is shared among all instances so that all instances see the same directory. So, for example, if an app saves uploaded files to the home directory, those files are immediately available to all instances.

Also, although an app has full read/write access to its own temporary local storage, that storage really isn't intended to be used directly by the application code.

See this doc for more details - [Operating system functionality on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#file-access)